# I'm getting a "string subscript out of range error". I can not figure out why

Tags: c++, string, function, for-loop

I searched the site but I am unable to find a solution to my problem. I tried making minor changes but nothing has solved it. I keep getting "string subscript out of range" error. I do not know why. Maybe I'm blind and I'm missing a small error somewhere. Now I'm here requesting aid.

Info on program: This program will input first and last name, validate it and apply case conversion. After the first name and last name have been entered by the user, it will clear the screen and display the names the user has entered. It will then input the product rating, validate it and apply case conversion.Display a heading followed by a bar chart corresponding to the 5 product values.

Edit: I want to say thank you to the people that helped me. I solved the issue finally thankfully to you guys. I have to say that there is a great community here and the response was superb. I'm going to class now but I will post my updated code for people in the future who might have the same problem. Thank you very much again guys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Name (string, string&, const int);
void Rating (string&, int[], const int);

void main()
{
    const int MAX_FIRST_NAME = 20;
    const int MAX_LAST_NAME  = 25;
    const int MAX_PRODUCTS   =  5;

    string  firstNameQuestion = "First Name";
    string  lastNameQuestion  = "Last  Name";

    string    firstName;
    string     lastName;
    string ratingString;

    int ratingInt [MAX_PRODUCTS];


    while (true)
    {
        Name (firstNameQuestion, firstName, MAX_FIRST_NAME);

        if (firstName == "Quit")
            break;

        Name (lastNameQuestion, lastName, MAX_LAST_NAME);

        if (lastName == "Quit")
            break;

        system ("cls");

        cout << "First Name: "  << firstName;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Last  Name: "  << lastName;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;

        Rating (ratingString, ratingInt, MAX_PRODUCTS);
    }   
}

void Name (string question, string& answer, const int MAX)
{
    int count;

    do
    {
        cout << question << " (" << MAX << " chars max. type \"quit\" to stop):     ";
        getline (cin, answer);
    }
    while (answer.empty() || answer.length() > MAX);

    answer[0] = toupper (answer[0]);

    for (count = 1; count < answer.length(); count++)
        answer[count] = tolower ( answer[count] );
}

void Rating (string& ratingString, int ratingInt[], const int MAX)
{
    int  count;
    int    who;

    for (count = 0; count < MAX; count++)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Rating for product no." << count + 1 << " (A to E): ";
            cin  >> ratingString[count];
            ratingString[count] = toupper (ratingString[count]);
        }   
        while (ratingString.empty() || ratingString.length() > 1 ||     ratingString[count] > 'E');
    }

    for (who = 0; who < MAX; who++)
    {
        if (ratingString[who] == 'A')
            ratingInt[who] = 10;

        if (ratingString[who] == 'B')
            ratingInt[who] = 8;

        if (ratingString[who] == 'C')
            ratingInt[who] = 6;

        if (ratingString[who] == 'D')
            ratingInt[who] = 4;

        else 
            ratingInt[who] = 2;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Consumer satisfaction bar chart: ";
    cout << endl;

    for (count = 0; count > MAX; count++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Product #" << count + 1 << "      ";

        for (who = 0; who > ratingInt[count]; who++)

            cout << "*";
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed C# from your tags as this is clearly C++.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead not the OP, was an editor

Answer (score 1):

Line 45

```
Rating (ratingString, ratingInt, MAX_PRODUCTS);
```

the ratingString is empty.
When it runs to Line76

```
    cin  >> ratingString[count];
```

you are referencing an index out of the boundary.

How about this edit:

```
    char cc;
    cin  >> cc;
    ratingString.push_back(cc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved the issue last night by not taking the variable from void main and instead making "string ratingString" in Input Rating. I will post my new code after I come back from class so people can see my changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the loop below, count reached to `MAX`

```
    for (count = 0; count < MAX; count++)
```

Then again in loop below, you are using `count++` and its going beyond the string `ratingString` length.

```
   for (who = 0; who < MAX; count++)
```

**To fix the issue, either use correct the index+increment or put a check on string length as well.**

```
   for (who = 0; who < MAX && who < ratingString.length(); who++)
```

**It's better to put the string length check in all the loops where character at string index is used.**

Comment: Even though that is an error that I missed. It did not solve the error. Good find though, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @user1855446 Still I think there is a problem. What if there are not as many characters as `MAX` in the names. You need to put the check on string length as well as I mentioned in the updated answer.

Comment: If I do as you say, the program skips the for-loops.

Comment: @user1855446 Which `for` loop is getting skipped? Make sure your string is populated. **If string unavailability(length=0) is causing the `for` loop to be skipped then that is the cause of your subscript error as well.**

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. I solved it last night with your help. Your reaction time to the thread was great, appreciate it.

Comment: @user1855446 If you think this was helpful, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the arrow down the vote count.